# parse search string for phrases and keywords

Tags: php, regex, string, parsing

i need to parse a search string for keywords and phrases in php, for example

string 1: `value of "measured response" detect goal "method valuation" study`

will yield: `value,of,measured reponse,detect,goal,method valuation,study`

i also need it to work if the string has:

1. no phrases enclosed in quotes,
2. any number of phrases encloses in quotes with any number of keywords outside the quotes,
3. only phrases in quotes,
4. only space-separated keywords.

i'm leaning towards using `preg_match` with the pattern `'/(\".*\")/'` to get the phrases into an array, then remove the phrases from the string, then finally work the keywords into the array. i just can't pull everything together!

i'm also thinking of replacing spaces outside quotes with commas. then explode them to an array. if that's a better option, how do i do that with `preg_replace`?

is there a better way to go about this? help! thanks much, everyone

Comment: Yes a much better way than regex - simply use the inbuilt function str_getcsv and set the delimiter to space and the enclosure to speech marks : `$array = str_getcsv($string, ' ', '"');`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
preg_match_all('/(?<!")\b\w+\b|(?<=")\b[^"]+/', $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($result[0]); $i++) {
    # Matched text = $result[0][$i];
}
```

This should yield the results you are looking for.

**Explanation :**

```
# (?<!")\b\w+\b|(?<=")\b[^"]+
# 
# Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «(?<!")\b\w+\b»
#    Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below with the match ending at this position (negative lookbehind) «(?<!")»
#       Match the character “"” literally «"»
#    Assert position at a word boundary «\b»
#    Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, etc.) «\w+»
#       Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
#    Assert position at a word boundary «\b»
# Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire match attempt fails if this one fails to match) «(?<=")\b[^"]+»
#    Assert that the regex below can be matched, with the match ending at this position (positive lookbehind) «(?<=")»
#       Match the character “"” literally «"»
#    Assert position at a word boundary «\b»
#    Match any character that is NOT a “"” «[^"]+»
#       Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
```

Comment: whoa. will work on this now, will defs let you know asap once i get it working.

Comment: follow-up: what if i want to ignore common words from those not enclosed in quotes? like `of`? let's say i have an array of disallowed words like `array ('at','the','and','of','in')`, how do i incorporate that into the approach? thanks again!

Comment: Wow, I use regex often but this kind of stuff is what separates the men (@FailedDev) from the boys (@davidethell).

Comment: one thing, though, @FailedDev , how do i modify the regex pattern to preserve a `hyphen` before a keyword or a phrase? like if the string is `value of "measured response" -detect goal -"method valuation" study`, the corresponding output will be `value,of,measured reponse,-detect,goal,-method valuation,study`?

Comment: i tried inserting `-?` and `\-?` before `\w` but it messes things up.. :/

Comment: Sorry. But I don't think you can do what you are asking for in one regex. You want to match something, then ignore something and then continue matching - all in one result. This sounds more of a replace funciton to me.

Comment: thanks, @FailedDev ! yeap, great idea, i already implemented the replacement thing. now to clarify my last comment: i also want to include terms that have a `hyphen` preceding them, such that  if the string is `value of "measured response" -detect goal -"method valuation" study`, the corresponding output will be `value,of,measured reponse,-detect,goal,-method valuation,study`. i tried inserting `-?` and `\-?` before `\w` but i still can't get it to work.. :D

Comment: hi again, @FailedDev , this already got me capturing `-detect`: `/(?<!")(-|\b)\w+\b|(?<=")\b[^"]+/`. is that correct? now if i could only get `-method valuation` right.. help..

Comment: @AnaBan As I said you will think more than a simple regex to do this. You should split the regex on spaces (not inside "" ) and then apply a replace regex to do what you want on each string separately.

Comment: oooh.. kk, workin on it. one last question, is my modification right? am i not breaking something by inserting `(-|\b)` in place of `\b` in the first pattern `(?<!")\b\w+\b` so that it's `(?<!")(-|\b)\w+\b`?

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to use a regular expression, the built in function `str_getcsv` can be used to explode a string with any given delimiter, enclosure and escape characters.

Really it is as simple as.

```
// where $string is the string to parse
$array = str_getcsv($string, ' ', '"');
```

Comment: Brilliant solution.

Comment: @crishoj I have my moments ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
$s = 'value of "measured response" detect goal "method valuation" study';
preg_match_all('~(?|"([^"]+)"|(\S+))~', $s, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => value
    [1] => of
    [2] => measured response
    [3] => detect
    [4] => goal
    [5] => method valuation
    [6] => study
)
```

The trick here is to use a *branch-reset* group: `(?|...|...)`.  It's just like an alternation contained in a non-capturing group - `(?:...|...)` - except that within each branch the capturing-group numbers start at the same number.  (For more info, see the [PCRE docs](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt) and search for `DUPLICATE SUBPATTERN NUMBERS`.)

Thus, the text we're interested in is always captured group #1.  You can retrieve the contents of group #1 for all matches via `$matches[1]`.  (That's assuming the PREG_PATTERN_ORDER flag is set; I didn't specify it like @FailedDev did because it's the default.  See the [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) for details.)

Comment: Could you post a perl test where this regex works? Or is it only supported in php? I would like to see it working but I can't get it to work with my tool.

Comment: amazing, alan, learned something new again. follow-up, though, what if i want to ignore common words from those not enclosed in quotes? like 'Array ( [1] => Array ( [1] => of ) )'? let's say i have an array of disallowed words like `array ('at','the','and','of','in')`, how do i incorporate that into the approach? thanks much!

Comment: Ana Ban, it's working for me: **[demo](http://ideone.com/WfW4I)**.  As for filtering out common words, that would be much easier to do afterward.  @FailedDev, in Perl the branch-reset group is only supported in v5.10 and later.  Try adding the `use v5.10;` pragma.