# Using REGEX to parse a search string with boolean operators

Tags: php, regex, string, parsing, search

I found this answer -
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7943464/1901367 - which gave me this really useful code allowing me to parse search strings that contained quotes and white space.

```
preg_match_all('/(?<!")\b\w+\b|(?<=")\b[^"]+/', $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

I wondered if someone could tell me how to alter this code so that it would leave boolean operators such as + and - intact because the current code strips them out.

I want to do fulltext boolean searches of my database making use of those operators and I am confused by this REGEX which I don't understand.

Example input and output.

Input: '"this is some" text here is -more -"exlude me"'
Output: [this is some] [text] [here] [is] [-more] [-exclude me] these would be in the $result array

So everything seperated by a space is an individual item unless it is a phrase enclosed in "". This works already but where I have -more and -"exlude me" the result currently would be [more] and [exclude me] losing the minus symbol which I want to keep.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide example inputs and your expected outputs for those inputs.

Comment: Done, I've added it to the question

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple regular expressions to yank out tokens, with the quotes and everything in them, and then pretty them up before you use them. Something like this:

```
function query_tokens($query)
{
    $regex = '/-?"[\pL\s]+"|-?\pL+/';

    preg_match_all($regex, $query, $tokens, PREG_SET_ORDER);

    foreach ($tokens as & $token)
    {
        $token = array_shift($token);

        $modifier = NULL;

        if ($token[0] === '-' || $token[0] === '+')
        {
            $modifier = $token[0];

            $token = substr($token, 1);
        }
        if ($token[0] === '"')
        {
            $token = trim($token, '"');
        }
        $token = $modifier.$token;
    }

    return $tokens;
}
```

The string used and result from the function:

```
var_dump(query_tokens('"this is some" text here is -more -"exlude me"'));
array (size=6)
  0 => string 'this is some' (length=12)
  1 => string 'text' (length=4)
  2 => string 'here' (length=4)
  3 => string 'is' (length=2)
  4 => string '-more' (length=5)
  5 => string '-exlude me' (length=10)
```

Regular expressions are great, but sometimes they can make things more complicated than they need to be.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot capture '-exclude me' using a regular expression because matches are always consecutive.  At best, you could modify the regular expression to match the '-more' token as such:

`(?<!")-?\b\w+\b|(?<=")\b[^"]+`